# How to export question- answers to PDF/DOC

Tags: feature-request

There are many questions which have replies running to more than 1 page
is it possible to export all the answers to PDF?

Comment: You mean if a question has more than 30 answers?

Comment: i'm not quite sure about the number of answers (30+ or so).
my objective is how to export a question and the list of ALL answers in a single document.
this will help in formatting and storage for future reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it's true that we don't provide any view of a question that actually shows more than 30 answers, is it?

Even the RSS feed for a question is limited to 30 answers.