# Is it possible to group questions and export them in PDF format?

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow, printing

Is it possible to group SO questions and export them in PDF format?

Sometimes I like reading offline better than reading on my screen. In this case, I prefer to print stuff. This could also be nice as reference reading, for example for in a waiting room or on the toilet at the office :).

I recently learned about the beauty of the book creator on Wikipedia. Is there anything like it on Stack Overflow? I found only [one similar question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36721), but it is about a single question with multiple answers, while I'd like to group related questions with answers into one PDF.

Comment: Yeah, bringing your office computer into the bathroom is a huge hassle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a couple of options:

1. [Stack Overflow ebooks for kindle](https://stackapps.com/questions/2035/stack-overflow-ebooks-for-kindle)
2. [StackPrinter](https://stackapps.com/questions/179/stackprinter-the-stack-exchange-printer-suite)

Comment: +1 for stackprinter. combined with cups-pdf, this makes a great way to archive those wonderful questions you want to be able to read offline. I've a couple like that.

Comment: I think I like stackprinter.  not as complete nor user friendly as the wikipedia books generator but good enough.  thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You could use the SO API's to create an external tool that does this pretty simply. Plenty of PDF generators out there as well :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's any need for the team to build this. As Ólafur Waage said, if you really needed it, build your own using the API! But I don't even think that is necessary. Mac OS and Linux can print to PDF with no additional software and there's [open source software](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdfcreator/) to do the same on Windows. Just print the pages to PDF yourself.

Comment: R, I don't think this question is about printing.  Just exporting questions/answers to a PDF file.

Comment: @jzd: Right, I meant "print the pages to PDF yourself", I will clarify

Comment: R,  yes much better, I understand your point now.