# Save Question page as PDF / pretty print (annotation-free) - @print media css?

Tags: feature-request, pdf

I would like to have a printout of a question with its answers as pdf, clean from annotations at the right, etc. Many websites already provide this "cleaned-up" look for printing/saving as pdf.

Is this worth implementing?

One option is providing a pretty printout, and another option is already providing a pdf for download (without going through a local pdf printer). I think that both are useful.

[How to export question- answers to PDF/DOC](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36721/how-to-export-question-answers-to-pdf-doc) asks about saving as pdf, but with a different objective (the requested feature, which is including all answers in the pdf, would be useful as part of my request, but the [answer for that](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/36789/232130) was already "No").

[Printing out Stack Overflow/Exchange Q&As including comments?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22877/printing-out-stack-overflow-questions) is also related, but also aimed at a different objective.

---

**Update**:

There is an external tool for this, see [this answer below](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/230625/232130). A native method in SO, perhaps borrowed from [StackApps.com StackPrinter](https://stackapps.com/questions/179/stackprinter-the-stack-exchange-printer-suite), would still be very useful.

Comment: Print preview in FireFox 26.0 shows [pretty much what you want](http://i.stack.imgur.com/HAC6b.png) for me now.

Comment: @Mołot - Almost. It has the top bar, and it appears as a small print (I guess this is due to selecting "Shrink to fit page width"; without that, printing is cropped). I had tried that too prior to posting.

Comment: Starting point: [All Your Stack Posts](http://stackapps.com/q/4306)

Comment: Does this app help: [StackPrinter: The Stack Exchange Printer Suite](http://stackapps.com/q/179)?

Comment: @MartijnPieters - I had found a reference to that app. I didn't try it, but a native method in SO would still be of much wider reach. Thanks.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - I have finally looked at stackprinter. It appears to do exactly what I was asking for. I would post your comment as an answer, so I (and others) can upvote. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

Someone already built a website, http://www.stackprinter.com/, that does just that: turn Stack Exchange posts into PDFs.

See the [StackApps.com StackPrinter page](https://stackapps.com/questions/179/stackprinter-the-stack-exchange-printer-suite) for more information and a list of current features.

At the time of this answer, the feature list included:

> - *Addons:*
>
>   1. [Greasemonkey script](http://userscripts-mirror.org/scripts/show/77298) - Adds a Printer-Friendly button on question's page (FF|Chrome)
>   2. [Bookmarklet](http://www.stackprinter.com/) - Allows you to print a question directly from question's page
> - *Favorites:*  lets you browse and print favorites users's questions from:
>
>   1. The Stack Exchange Network
>   2. Delicious social bookmarking
> - *TopVoted:* top voted questions by tags
> - *TopPrinted:* StackPrinter top printed questions
> - *Deleted:* popular [deleted questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/73455/popular-deleted-questions-list) archive
> - *MySE:* for printing all your Stack Exchange stuff